# How to transfer files from windows to HortonWorks sandbox?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, vmware, hortonworks-data-platform

I tried using `-copyFromLocal` command to copy input file to HDFS but it is throwing error that could not locate file.

```
hadoop fs -mkdir MapReduceInput

hadoop fs -copyFromLocal d:/demodata.txt MapReduceInput/
```

error:

Also, need to give path of jar located in local system to run MapReduce job.
How can copy input files, jars to sandbox local system ? I am using vmware & windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

Use Winscp for copying the files from windows to any unix based server like Hortonwork Sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

the -copyFromLocal copies file from sandbox to hdfs not from windows to sandbox.

you need to scp the file from windows to sandbox using the scp command in the sandbox